# Logging the errors to azure blob

Tags: azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-databricks, python-logging

I am trying to log errors to azure blob but, its not creating any table in the blob. I have gone through many docs and also searched for ans in stackoverflow as well. Please help me with this.
Thanks

below is the code

def log():

```
import logging
import sys
from azure_storage_logging.handlers import BlobStorageRotatingFileHandler

mystorageaccountname='***'
mystorageaccountkey='***'

_LOGFILE_TMPDIR = mkdtemp()

logger = logging.getLogger('service_logger')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
log_formater = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(process)d - %(message)s')
azure_blob_handler = TableStorageHandler(account_name=mystorageaccountname,
                                         account_key=mystorageaccountkey,
                                         protocol='https',
                                         table='logtable',
                                         batchsize=100,
                                         extra_properties=None, 
                                         partition_key_formatter=None, 
                                         row_key_formatter=None, 
                                         is_emulated=False)
logger.addHandler(azure_blob_handler)

logger.warning('warning message')
```

Comment: Based on this link: https://github.com/michiya/azure-storage-logging and according to your code, your logging data should go in Azure Table Storage as you're using TableStorageHandler. Please check tables instead of blob containers.

Comment: Its not creating any table as well. I also tried with BlobStorageRotatingFileHandler to create a file but i am unable to see any file.

Answer (score 1):

According to the code you provided, you use `TableStorageHandler` to store log. It will help us store log in Azure table storage instead of Azure blob storage. Please find your logs in Azure table.

Besides, if you want to store your log in Azure blob, please refer to the following code

```
import logging
    import sys
    from azure_storage_logging.handlers import BlobStorageRotatingFileHandler

    mystorageaccountname='***'
    mystorageaccountkey='***'

    logger = logging.getLogger('service_logger')
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    log_formater = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(process)d - %(message)s')
    azure_blob_handler = BlobStorageRotatingFileHandler(filename = 'service.log', 
                                                        account_name=mystorageaccountname,
                                                        account_key=mystorageaccountkey,
                                                        maxBytes= 5,
                                                        container='service-log')
    azure_blob_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    azure_blob_handler.setFormatter(log_formater)
    logger.addHandler(azure_blob_handler)

    logger.warning('warning message')
```

For more details, please refer to the [document](https://pypi.org/project/azure-storage-logging/)

---

## Update

When we use`BlobStorageRotatingFileHandler`, the log does not upload if the content does not reach till maxBytes

My test code

```
import logging
import sys
from azure_storage_logging.handlers import BlobStorageRotatingFileHandler

mystorageaccountname='blobstorage0516'
mystorageaccountkey=''

logger = logging.getLogger('service_logger')
log_formater = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(process)d - %(message)s')
azure_blob_handler = BlobStorageRotatingFileHandler(filename = 'service.log', 
                                                        account_name=mystorageaccountname,
                                                        account_key=mystorageaccountkey,
                                                        maxBytes=5,
                                                        container='service-log')
azure_blob_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
azure_blob_handler.setFormatter(log_formater)
logger.addHandler(azure_blob_handler)

logger.warning('warning message')
```

[image]

Comment: Its not creating any table as well. I also tried with BlobStorageRotatingFileHandler to create a file but i am unable to see any file.