# DataFactory ondemand HDInsight cluster logs to Azure Blob: "BlobStorageRotatingFileHandler"

Tags: apache-spark, logging, pyspark, azure-data-factory, azure-blob-storage

I am running spark scripts on Azure Datafactory pipeline with on-demand HDInsight cluster.
I want to save the pipeline logs to Azure container. Trying to implement this :

[Logging the errors to azure blob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61607503/logging-the-errors-to-azure-blob?rq=3)

But I keep getting No module named azure_storage_logging.handlers when I run my script with this log logic mentioned in the above link.

How do I do a "pip install" for this module inside my spark scripts which I am running on the datafactory pipeline?

Or any other alternative way to implement the log logic in my spark script ?

Comment: Are you ok with using azure databricks instead of HDInsight cluster? It gives additional options for  adding libraries.

Comment: no, I am restricted with working on Datafctory's on-demand hdinsights  for now

Answer (score 0):

Add the following Python code at the start of your code, so that it will install the necessary packages.

```py
import os

try:
    from azure_storage_logging.handlers import BlobStorageRotatingFileHandler
    print("Module is installed.")
except ImportError:
    print("Module is not installed. Installing...")
    os.system('pip install azure-storage==0.36.0 azure-storage-logging')
    from azure_storage_logging.handlers import BlobStorageRotatingFileHandler
```

Code:

```py
import logging
import os

try:
    from azure_storage_logging.handlers import BlobStorageRotatingFileHandler
    print("Module is installed.")
except ImportError:
    print("Module is not installed. Installing...")
    os.system('pip install azure-storage==0.36.0 azure-storage-logging')
    from azure_storage_logging.handlers import BlobStorageRotatingFileHandler

mystorageaccountname='acc_name'
mystorageaccountkey='key'

logger = logging.getLogger('service_logger')
log_formater = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(process)d - %(message)s')
azure_blob_handler = BlobStorageRotatingFileHandler(filename = 'service.log', 
                                                        account_name=mystorageaccountname,
                                                        account_key=mystorageaccountkey,
                                                        maxBytes=5,
                                                        container='service-log')
azure_blob_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
azure_blob_handler.setFormatter(log_formater)
logger.addHandler(azure_blob_handler)

logger.warning('warning message')
```

**Output** in `service.log`

```
2023-12-27  12:35:13,292 - service_logger - WARNING - 16456 - warning message
```

Comment: Thanks for you response. I tried this. I am getting this info:

`===DEBUG ASSISTANCE=== If you are seeing an error here please try the following to successfully install cryptography: Upgrade to the latest pip and try again. This will fix errors for most users. See: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/#upgrading-pip===DEBUG ASSISTANCE===`
so what I did : 

`os.system('pip3 install --upgrade pip')`
`os.system('pip3 install azure-storage==0.36.0 azure-storage-logging')`

Now I am getting this error with it : PermissionError: [Errno 13] **Permission denied: '/home/.local'**

Comment: run it as administrator.

Comment: `pip install --upgrade --user pip
pip install --user azure-storage==0.36.0 azure-storage-logging
` try this. it will install packages in home dir.

Comment: Yes, I tried it. With **pip**:
->. OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zipp-1.2.0.dist-info'

-> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/OpenSSL/crypto.py:14: CryptographyDeprecationWarning: Python 2 is no longer supported by the Python core team.Support for it is now deprecated in cryptography, and will be removed in the next release from cryptography import utils, x509

->. OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zipp-1.2.0.dist-info'

-> ImportError: No module named azure_storage_logging.handlers

Comment: And if I try **pip3**:
1. PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/.local' 
2.  If you are seeing an error here please try the following tosuccessfully install cryptography:Upgrade to the latest pip and try again. This will fix errors for most users. See: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/#upgrading-pip
3.  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setuptools_rust'
4. Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-5x9fjxdf/cryptography/
5. ImportError: No module named azure_storage_logging.handlers

Comment: what is the python version you are using in hdinsight cluster.

Comment: When the HDInsight cluster is getting created through DataFactory, I am seeing on it's "overview" page->"Cluster type, HDI version: spark 2.4 (HDI 4.0)"

In my spark script, If I include : `platform.python_version()`-->2.7.12 & aa`spark.version`--> 2.4

As I am running my spark script on DataFactory's on-demand HDInsight,  won't I be able to update the python version through script ?

Comment: Hi @JayashankarGS
any more suggestions if possible ? :)

Comment: Try updating the python either through script or when creating hdinsight resource.

Comment: Hi @@JayashankarGS. I made some progress on this: In Hdinsight linked service, I mentioned the "spark version" option as 3.1. This worked. Now in my script if I do :`pyspark.__version__` --> 3.1.3 ;;`platform.python_version`--> 3.8.10;; `pip.__version__`---> 21.1.1 Now when I include the : 

`os.system('pip install --user azure-storage==0.36.0 azure-storage-logging')` 

I am getting this error: OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/distpackages/zipp-1.2.0.dist-info'

Comment: Still it is trying to install in python 2. I guess the cluster is not allowing to install any package. Can you run shell script with super user permission.  If yes add pip install script in it.

Comment: There is "script action" option in the hdinsight linked service. There under "script uri" I mentioned a container file to a `.sh` file path. In it, I mentioned with: `sudo /usr/bin/anaconda/bin/conda create --prefix /usr/bin/anaconda/envs/py35new python=3.5 anaconda=4.3 --yes
sudo /usr/bin/anaconda/bin/conda install azure-storage-logging -n py35new --yes
sudo /usr/bin/anaconda/bin/conda install azure-storage=0.36.0 -n py35new --yes` as shown: 
[link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/spark/apache-spark-python-package-installation).but still no import is happening